# My JavaScript variable not able to accept object which I have send using Django render() method

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, python-3.x

I was trying to fetch Django object in JSON format to my javascript variable. I have used **from django.core import serializers** predefined method available in Django, to convert it into JSON format. When I was trying to fetch that object directly into Jinja tag then it prints all the data, but when I was trying to get that data in Javascript variable then it won't work.

**view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Employee
from django.core import serializers
import json

def home(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", Employee.objects.all())
    return render(request,'home.html',{'data':data})
```

**home.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% extends 'masterpage.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    **{{data | safe}}**(go below for output)
    <form action="checkEmail" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="text" name="emailId" placeholder="Enter Email Id">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data=eval('('+'{{data}}'+')');
        var p=10;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=p
        console.log(p)
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output** : [{"model": "journal.employee", "pk": 1, "fields": {"ename": "Piyush Jiwnae", "eemail": "jiwanepiyush@gmail.com"}}]

I can see the output for direct use of jinja tag in HTML but when I try to get that value in javascript variable it won't come and as shown in code I was trying to show that data and *var p=10; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=p* this value also not printed on console.

Comment: is alert(data) is working?

Comment: @sandeep - no, even that also not working

Answer (score 0):

you could pass data as JSON and parse this object in js with JSON.parse

Comment: no man still it not working, forget about the JSON object my question is why not var p=10 value also not shown on console ??

Comment: by using data = serializers.serialize("json", Employee.objects.all()) I can successfully send the JSON data but not getting JSON data on JavaScript variable

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly your script is raising an error at that line:

```
var data=eval('('+'{{data}}'+')');
```

saying something like

```
SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&'
```

In the raw format your data renders to something like:

```
[{&quot;model&quot;: &quot;stack.employee&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;:
```

If you mark data variable as safe you should get a proper json object:

```
var data=eval('('+'{{data|safe}}'+')');
```

**Edit: Another issue in your code:**

Your extends tag in the wrong place. You should put `{% extends 'masterpage.html' %}` at the top of the template, not in your `<body>` tag. And then you should take out the `<head>` tag in your template because this is probably already in your `masterpage.html`

Comment: No, even though I have passed like **var data=eval('('+'{{data}}'+')');** thus, but still I didnt get any error on my console.

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion also, but still it's not working.

Comment: Then I beleive there is another issue. See my post edit. If that still doee not work please also post your ```masterpage.html```